# I have a problem with multiple inputs and accessing them inside a nested loop and printing only one output

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, scope, nested-loops

I have problem with one loop exercise. I have written 3  possible answers and my code failed each time. My counter failed, and I have a problem with the scope of variables and nested loops.

I have an array of food, and I have to find the one food with the best vowels to length ratio and print it to the console.
First I tried creating 3 variables two to compare with each other and one to store the result in it, and that gave me undefined for parts of the array. I expected that food3 would have all the iteration of i, but it had only
**i[2]**, and food2 had
**i[1], i[undefined], i[3]**.

In my second try had 2 variables, but my counter failed.

```js
const getGets = (arr) => {
  let index = 0;

  return () => {
    const toReturn = arr[index];
    index += 1;
    return toReturn;
  };
};

// Test input
const testInput = [
  '4', 'pizza', 'macaroni', 'kiufte', 'banica'
];

const gets = this.gets || getGets(testInput);
const n = +gets();

let vowels
let food = '';
let ratio
let counter = 0;

for (let i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
  let food1 = gets(); // pizza, undefined, kiufte, undefined
  let food2 = gets();
  let vowels1 = 0
  let vowels2 = 0
  let ratio1 = 0
  let ratio2 = 0

  for (let element of food1) {
    console.log(element) // failed here, because of food1

    if (element === 'a' || element === 'o' || element === 'u' || element === 'e' || element === 'i') {
      counter++;
      continue;
    }
  }
  vowels1 = vowels1 + counter;
  retio1 = vowels1 / food1.length;
  retio2 = vowels2 / food2.length;

  if (ratio1 >= ratio2) {
    ratio1 = ratio
    ratio2 = ratio1
    food1 = food
    food2 = food1
    vowels1 = vowels
    vowels2 = vowels1
  }
  console.log(`${food} ${vowels}/${food.length}`)
  couner = 0;
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  Please include a [mcve] demonstrating the problem *in the question itself* and indicate specifically in that example what problem you are observing.  To learn more about this community and how we can help you, please start with the [tour] and read [ask] and its linked resources.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My answer creates an object to store the results. Then it loops through the passed array and uses a regular expression to check for the number of vowels. Then it checks to see if the vowels variable is valid and returns the number of vowels if not returns 0, then is divides that by the word length.

After that the result object is checked to see if the word's ratio is greater than one that is already stored. If the new ratio is better, it is stored.

```js
const testInput = [
  '4', 'pizza', 'macaroni', 'kiufte', 'banica'
];

function compareRatios(input) {
  let result = {"word" : "","ratio" : 0,"vowels" : 0};
  
  input.forEach((word) =>{
    let vowels = word.match(/[aeiou]/gi);
    ratio = ((vowels) ? vowels.length : 0) / word.length
    
    if(result.ratio < ratio)
      result = {"word" : word,"ratio" : ratio,"vowels" : vowels.length};
  });
  
  console.log(`${result.word} ${result.ratio} ${result.vowels}`)
}

compareRatios(testInput)
```